# Where to find a source "Authorizing..." message comes from in a Blazor Web Assembly app?

Tags: asp.net-identity, blazor-webassembly

In a simple Blazor Web Assembly App created in Visual Studio with the "Individual User Accounts" option enabled, there is a message "Authorizing..." that appears on page loading:

[image]

In an attempt to change its representation, I'm struggling to find where it comes from. Tried to search:

- a solution;
- "All" scaffolded identity pages;
- AuthenticationService.js;
- blazor.webassembly.js;

Any ideas where it can hide?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out it is a default value of an [`AuthorizeRouteView`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/71a046bd88f9ce469e76ddea492de02bfae79252/src/Components/Authorization/src/AuthorizeRouteView.cs) component's parameter `Authorizing`. To change it just needed to set  fragment explicitly:

```
        <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
            <Authorizing>
                <div class="spinner"></div>
            </Authorizing>
            <NotAuthorized>
                @if (!context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                {
                    <RedirectToLogin />
                }
                else
                {
                    <p>You are not authorized to access this resource.</p>
                }
            </NotAuthorized>
        </AuthorizeRouteView>
```